# How to fix lag when using Office shortcuts (Alt + )?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

Everytime I press Alt + any shortcut (ex. Alt + HOI), it takes Excel about 5 seconds to actually perform the function. I'm not sure what's going on, but it seems to be arising from the fact that each time I press 'Alt', then 'H', then 'I', etc, there are animations that occur in the ribbon. When using legacy shorcuts (Alt OAC, the equivalent of HOI), which do not have any animation, there is no lag! Does anyone know how to fix this? I have done the following to troubshoot:

1. Disable hardware acceleration
2. Disable animations
3. Use Regedit to add keys to disable the above
4. Set computer to high-performance mode
5. Disabled all plugins
6. Restarted the computer, repaired Office, reinstalled Office (I don't think resetting the computer is going to help as this has occurred since I got it).

I'm using Excel 2013 by the way. Thanks in advance, I've read numerous posts about this issue online, but no one seems to have a good solution, but I'm hoping this community can help!

For a video of the problem, please go here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8-mso_2013_release/microsoft-office-alt-ribbon-shortcut-lags/49796ec8-f7f0-42e5-a25c-4df23a2a3721

Answer (score 0):

From the link it seems this problem occurs only on MACs running Windows running Office.

I suggest you upgrade to a newer version of Office. This is likely a display driver issue that might be fixed in newer versions. You could of course also try to update or downgrade (to a 2012/13 version) of your display driver.

From the video though it would seem the problem lies with loading of icons in the dropdown menus. Icons are cached. Is your drive perhaps full or the cache size limited perhaps to the point that Windows regularly clears the cache? You could perhaps look into ways or registry edits that would disabled the display of icons in context menus. I seem to recall this was possible at least with some Windows Explorer context menu editor I used many many moons a go (possibly still on Windows 98).